# How map array of array to single assoc array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, php-7

I have:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "FNAME" => "nullable|string"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    "LNAME" => "nullable|string"
  ]
]
```

And I try to get:

```
array:1 [
  "key" => "value"
]
```

I try map it, but has problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two simple ways:

```
print_r(array_merge(...$arr));
// if `...` is not available (php < 5.6), then:
print_r(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$array = [
    [
        "FNAME" => "nullable|string",
    ],
    [
        "LNAME" => "nullable|string",
    ]
];

$newArray = [];

foreach ($array as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        $newArray[$key] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Will output:

```
Array
(
    [FNAME] => nullable|string
    [LNAME] => nullable|string
)
```